# Double型をString型に変換すると「e-」がついてしまう

Tags: swift

こんにちは。質問失礼いたします。
Double型をString型に変換した際に0.00のような「0」が続く数値の場合、
「e-」のような浮動小数点表記になってしまいます。
これを回避する方法をどなたかご存知ないでしょうか...

```
import Foundation

let a = 0.138274823423
let b = 0.000021312312

let at = String(a)
let bt = String(b)

print(at) // 0.138274823423
print(bt) // 2.1312312e-05
```

**NumberFormatter**が使えると思い、以下のようにしてみましたが解決しませんでした。

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

let ans = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: b))

print(ans!) // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

自己回答のように`String(format:)`も使えるでしょうが、`NumberFormatter`でも同様のことはできます。

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
//ここで桁数を指定
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 8

let ans = formatter.string(from: b as NSNumber)

print(ans!) //-> 0.00002131
```

`String(format:)`による変換は、ローカライズを考慮してくれないので、

- ユーザに見せるための文字列ではない
- 将来にわたって他国語対応の必要はない

と言う場合だけに使用を限られた方がいいでしょう。

Appleのクラスリファレンスは、まだまだ記述も少なく、コード例もほとんど見られないのでとても使いやすいとは言えないのですが、一応示しておきます。
[NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)
[minimumFractionDigits](http://minimumFractionDigits)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます...
String -> Double などの変換で検索すると,  formatについてはなかなかいい記事が出てくれなくて,つい質問を書いてしまいました。助かりました

Comment: 確かに「変換」「format」なんかのキーワードでは、`NumberFormatter`を使う記事はこちらでもなかなか見つかりませんでした。「swift NumberFormatter」と直に指定しても、swift以外の記事が多数ヒットしたりして難しいところです。私が試した限りObjective-Cでのクラス名「NSNumberFormatter」で検索した方がわかりやすい記事が多く出てきました。Objective-Cでのクラス名がわかっている情報を取りたいときなどには、一応覚えておかれるといいかと思います。ちなみにそれなりの時間検索していい記事にヒットしなかった場合、遠慮なさらずに質問(&自己回答)を書かれるのは、多くの方に有用なことだと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0):

すみません。自己解決です。>人<

```
let b = 0.000021318312
//ここで桁数を指定
let ans = String(format: "%.8f", b)

print(ans) // 0.00002132
```

以下参考

> [文字列フォーマット Apple リファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)